# What's the correct term for returning something as an out parameter?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, terminology, out-parameters

I hope this question is on topic.

I was doing  code review and stumbled upon the following function:

```
bool SomeFunc(std::string& o_xxx, char& o_yyy);
```

This function is used to retrieve the values of `xxx` and `yyy` of some class by means of out parameters.

The comments (which are later used for auto-documentation) say:

> ... this function returns by reference the [xxx] and [yyy]...

Obviously the function returns a boolean value indicating success or failure. So the sentence above need to be rephrased. But how? What's the correct term (if any) for returning something, as it were, by means of an out parameter, or, in other words, populating an argument passed by reference?

The question is tagged language agnostic, because it's not C++ specific. But it's also tagged C++ because the example is in C++.

Comment: I usually say something to the effect of "the function returns a value indicating success or failure. In case of success `o_xxx` will have the value of [xxx] and `o_yyy` will have the value of [yyy]. In case of failure, the arguments are unchanged.".

Comment: Out parameters are sometimes used because there is more than one parameter to return. If you combine them into a class you can just return an instance. Sometimes out parameters are used for efficiency though. Finally, why are you passing data around? Encapsulate: tell, don't ask!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: "In case of failure, the arguments are unchanged" - and note that this is a strong exception guarantee. So if you say this, be sure to assign to `o_xxx` in the function *before* assigning to `o_yyy`, since the string assignment is the one that can fail. Or use swaps.

Comment: @SteveJessop Oh, sure. Alternatively, if it's not easy to provide such guarantee, you could just say "(...) the arguments will have unspecified values".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Upon success, `SomeFunc` stores in `o_xxx` and `o_yyy` the values ..."; *stores in* is how the Linux manpage `strtoul(3)` describes what that function does with its `endptr` argument.

Though I've also heard the phrase "return in" often enough with reference-typed out parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

In simplest words:

> Function `SomeFunc()` *can* **modify** parameters `xxx(std::string)` and `yyy(char)`
>   and returns success or failure (`bool`).

Comment: Note that this isn't (in .NET terms) a `ref` parameter. It's an `out` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Consider the MSDN way. [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Return value is described in its own section.
Manipulations with output parameters are described in their own sections and may be optionally repeated in the Return Value section.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using doxygen, then this would do :

```
/**
 *- Description : This function ...
 *
 * @param[out] xxx ...
 * @param[out] yyy ...
 *
 * @return true for ..., false otherwise
 *
 ***********************************************************************/
```